# On the gist of $\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, random-variables

As far as I understand the reason we have $\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ all over the probability theory is that it tells us what questions are answerable by $X_1,\ldots, X_n$.

Say, we run an experiment and get some (secret) $\omega\in\Omega$. We also have some $M\in\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ and would like to know whether $\omega\in M$ or not. What we do know are $X_1(\omega),\ldots, X_n(\omega)$. Can we now tell whether $\omega\in M$? If so, how?

I have tried to construct a counterexample (to get the idea of how to prove it) and they all failed because my $M$ was not in $\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ (which is the smallest $\sigma$-field such that the functions are r.v.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Simpler solution:* The $\sigma$-field generated by $X_1\dots, X_n$ is just the inverse images 
of all Borel subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is,
$$\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)=\{(X_1,\dots,X_n)^{-1}(B):B\in{\cal B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\}.$$
This means that there is some $B\in{\cal B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that 
$$M=\{\omega\in\Omega: (X_1(\omega),\dots, X_n(\omega))\in B\}.$$
Therefore you can tell whether or not $\omega\in M$ just from the values
 $X_1(\omega),\dots, X_n(\omega)$.

---

*First solution:* 
 By the [Doob-Dynkin lemma,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) if $M\in\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ then you can write the indicator function of $M$ as a Borel function of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$:
$$1_M(\omega)=f(X_1(\omega),\dots,X_n(\omega)).$$ You can tell whether or not $\omega\in M$ from the values of $X_1(\omega)$, $\dots$, $X_n(\omega)$.